# Parse textual ER representation with RegEx into Java Objects

Tags: java, regex, parsing, entity-relationship

I need to parse a textual Model (e.g. http://pastebin.com/p7tskdjj) into Java Objects. The data structure seems to be clear for me, but I am struggling with filling it with data.
In the example *ITEM*, *ORDER* and *SUPPLIER* are Entity-Types with attributes/keys and *assigned* and *sup* are Relationship-Types with also attributes and keys.
The Entity-Types are recognized by the first empty line following three blanks and a string. Attributes got six blanks.
The Relationship-Types are similar.

The following is a little code-example. My Problem is the RegEx in the *split* function.

```
String splitline[] = null;
String content = new String(Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get("PATH")));
splitline = content.split("\\n\\s{3}");
int cnt = 0;
for (String string : splitline) {
    System.out.print(cnt++ + string);
}
```

Looking for the simple white-spaces seems not to work. I also tried *\p{Blank}{4}*. It is my first time handling with RegEx. I read some tutorials but I found nothing that I could use for my problem.

My goal is to parse the text to create an ArrayList within all Entity-Type with their (Key)Attributes and the same for Relation-Ship.

I am looking forward to archive help with this issue and I am glad if someone has a better idea how to solve that.

Comment: That file on pastebin: surely this isn't meant to be an example of the text data file you want to decompose?

Comment: I am not sure if I understood your question. It is a textual representation of a Entity-Relationship-Model from DB-Main. This will be my Input for a future transformation.

Comment: Right - so I thought, too. But you are talking about parsing a text file into a data structure. Now, that could be a representation of the *Model* or something representing data entities, i.e., Items, Orders and Suppliers. Which is it?

Comment: I edit the question text: This is the example Model: https://www.dropbox.com/s/mlxee1n0g3b9iga/example_schema.pdf?dl=0. The Pastebin is the textual representation. And I need to create Relationship and Entity objects in Java so I can run algorithms on them.

Comment: Clearer now. - A split based on some regular expression isn't really helpful here. You'll have to read this text file line by line, keeping track of the state you are in and handle lines accordingly. A line containing an uppercase word is an entitity header. I'm not sure what to do with the following lines. Do you have a class for representing an Entity? After an empty line, there are definitions of relationships: two spaces, a word, a space and '(' identify a relationship header. Again: not sure what to do with the following lines, and do you have a class for representing a relationship?

Comment: Thanks so far laune! I will try to follow your advice by scanning it line by line. To answer your question: I have classes for both. But the Relationship-Types are just lowercase in this example.

Comment: If you want more suggestions I'd need to see these classes and how the text lines relate to their properties. Good luck!